# ReactJS: How can I monitor the re-rendering process?

Tags: reactjs

Is there any way I can keep track of the React components that are being re-rendered?

For example, I'm making an API call, and upon reply, I change the state of some parent components, so all the child components are being re-rendered too (am I right in this one?).

How can I monitor which parent component initiates the re-render process and which children are rendered as a result (and how many times every component is being re-rendered)?

I'm aware I can inject some kind of console.log pattern in every component and just monitor the browser console, but I was looking for a more sophisticated solution.

Comment: Have you looked at the [React devtools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi) browser plugin? You can watch the components change directly.

Comment: I do have the React devtools but I never noticed the Trace React Updates feature! It's the visual equivalent of what I was looking for! The only problem is that it works really well when you're trying to get a general idea of what is being updated, but it's really hard to notice if a component is updated twice by mistake.

Comment: It turns out that the visual indications by the devtools change color according to how small was the timespan between consecutive renders of the element. The small the timespan, the "hotter" the color becomes. Still, we could make far better use of a log rather than the visual indication only.

Answer (score 0):

You could start by logging the new state or properties in the componentWillUpdate() life cycle method, that will be called immediately before each render (except for the first one).

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillupdate

Comment: Actually, that was my initial approach, but I would have to override the componentShouldUpdate on every component I'm using. I was hoping for a cleaner solution.

Comment: You're right. As another user pointed out, in React terms a re-render (as in, calling the render function) will be triggered any time a component receives new state or props, unless the shouldComponentUpdate function is defined with logic to distinguish if it's really necessary to render. If you definitely need to do this, I wouldn't go about it by changing your existing components, but using Higher Order Components instead.